# Removing all table border margins

Tags: margins, tabularx, border

I have a macro that generates a Latex table, which I need to fit inside a box (well, a Label) in Asymptote. I would like to have the bounding box edges coincide with the table edges. This does not happen because of the table border margins, as shown in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{lightOrange}{HTML}{FFD993}
\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{red}{gray}{%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}%
    \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|X|}%
        \hline
        \cellcolor{lightOrange} Some text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}%

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove all the margins around the table so that it perfectly fits the minipage?

I can remove the top and bottom margins using something like \vspace*{-3pt}, but it does not seem very elegant, and still leaves the left and right margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's the desired result:

[image]

two changes are necessary:

- `tabularx˛` size had to be equal to`minipage` size. the simplest way to achieve this is determine size with `\linewidth`
- `\fboxsep` has to be set to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightOrange}{HTML}{FFD993}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fcolorbox{red}{gray}{%
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}%
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidthe}{X}
        \cellcolor{lightOrange} Some text\\
      \end{tabularx}%
    \end{minipage}%
} 
\end{document}
```

- purpose of use `tabularx` in `\minipage` is not known, however the same result is possible to achieve on the simpler way by use of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{lightOrange}{HTML}{FFD993}

\newtcolorbox{alert}[1][]%
    {
    width=#1,
    colback=lightOrange,
    colframe=red,
    sharp corners
    }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alert}[7cm]
    \lipsum*[11]
    \end{alert}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to use tabularx because the macro actually builds a table. The code I provided was just an example with one cell in the table.

Comment: you can insert table in `tcolorbox`, even more `tcolorbox` package provide special box for `tabularx`

Answer (score 1):

Needless to use a  `tabular(x)`: a simple `\parbox`{5cm}`will do, withe optional arguments to control height and position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{lightOrange}{HTML}{FFD993}

\begin{document}

\fboxrule = 1pt
\fcolorbox{red}{lightOrange}{%
    \parbox[c][3ex]{5cm}{ Some text}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output image]